# Is there any way to put a Line Feed (LF) in a Trello List title, or otherwise have a Title and details?

Tags: trello

I struggle with in Trello is that Lists don't have descriptions. So I'm torn between short (but vague) titles and clear (but unweieldy) titles.

One solution:

TITLE
description

Kludge:   ------ TITLE  -------- description
Which usually will wrap to :
------ TITLE  -------- 
description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

All the keyboard events are consumed, so you cannot enter a linefeed using the keyboard.  However if you have text written externally (such as in a notepad) which contains a linefeed, you can cut-n-paste that into the element editor.

However the joy is a short lived, as the text is sanitized as soon as it is submitted; removing all training white space and also collapses the unprintable characters such as the newly created newline.

So in short, No you cannot enter a line feed into Trello's list text.